# How to block Angry Birds Toons movies in iOS App (like Angry Brids Go)

Tags: ios, applications, parental-controls

Angry Birds Go comes with a menu item where you can watch Angry Birds Toons and other movies. Is it possible to block these movies (as a "parental control")?

For example: Is the server serving the movies known such that I can block the server in the router?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.

This is a solution:
http://www.imore.com/how-block-specific-websites-being-accessed-safari-iphone-and-ipad

It was slightly different on the Air but very easy to figure out. I just checked "Specific Websites Only" and it was already populated with JUST kid friendly stuff that did not include the birds :)

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could block the IP and/or domain in your router.  For instance, on my Linksys router you can [block any url by editing the router's settings](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/GetArticle.aspx?docid=0ef3e662367b4864850419e217dbfa23_5575.xml&pid=80&converted=0).  However, not all routers have this functionality, for example I also have a router provided by Xfinity that doesn't provide any domain-specific filtering.

If that doesn't work, you might be out of luck. Other than disabling in app purchases, there's no easy way to get granular control over particular functions within an iOS app.  You could turn the device's wifi off altogether (i.e. Airplane Mode) and lock it with parental controls, but that would turn off all web browsing, email, etc.

Comment: Yes. But: do you know the url/ip/address space of the server(s)?

Comment: I don't, but you could log the iPad's traffic with airportd or wireshark and find out:  http://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/sniffing-ipad-traffic/

Answer (score 0):

To block Angry birds toons you need to blacklist https://www.angrybirds.com/ on either the router or locally on the the device.

Comment: Can you add some more detail regarding *how* the domain could be blocked on the device?

Answer (score 0):

To block ToonsTV on the iPad I added https://sdk.toons.tv/ to the "Never Allow" list in Settings>Restrictions>Websites